# Columns are not fully spanning a three column table

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablelayout

I'm brand new to html, so I'm sure this is a basic question.

I have a table with three columns. I want the first column to span 40% of the width of the table, the second 30% and the third 30%. I have the whole table in a div. But the columns are not spanning the entire table:

[image]

Here is my html:

```
<div class="TableWrap">
    <table id="PowerPlantTable" border="1">

        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="silver">
                <th class="firstColumn">Power Plant</th>
                <th class="secondColumn">MW Output</th>
                <th class="thirdColumn">MW Capacity</th>
            </tr>  
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>BRUCEA-G2</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And here is my css:

```
.TableWrap{
    margin: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

#PowerPlantTable{
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;   
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size:12.0px;
}

.firstColumn{
   width:40%;
}

.secondColumn{
    width:30%;
}

.thirdColumn{
    width:30%;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display:block` from #PowerPlantTable.

Tables are by default `display:table`.

Comment: No problem. I wish I had more of explanation as to why you were experiencing the behaviour you had. My guess is that browsers run an algorithm specific to rendering table elements and when the table wasn't displayed as a table it got confused on how to properly render the `<tr>` and `<td>` within the table.